# Scylla datacenter and Cassandra datacenter in same cluster

Tags: cassandra, nosql, database-migration, cassandra-3.0, scylla

I have running 21 node Cassandra cluster with 150+ schema and about 20 TB data.I need to shift the schema and data from Cassandra to 7 node Scylla in no downtime scenario.

Both Scylla and Cassandra support the same cqlsh version and almost same in distributing the  data and gossiping.

To shift the data I am trying to create new Scylla datacenter in existing Cassandra cluster and update the Keyspace topology to have Scylla also in the DC list of replication then Bootstrap/Rebuild the Scylla node in the cluster.

To do this I am getting error of TCP connection failure when adding seed list in node.

Scylla Error:-

> scylla:  [shard 0] rpc - client 10.200.1.2:34236: server connection dropped: connection is closed 
>   scylla:  [shard 0] rpc - client 10.200.1.2:7000: fail to connect: Connection refused.

Cassandra Error:-

> [MessagingService-Outgoing-/10.200.2.2-Gossip]  OutboundTcpConnection.java:411 - Socket to /10.200.2.2 closed
>   [HANDSHAKE-/10.200.2.2] OutboundTcpConnection.java:570 - Cannot handshake version with /10.200.2.2
>   [HANDSHAKE-/10.200.2.2] OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /10.200.2.2

Please help me if anyone has done this already or any better idea of shifting data without downtime, without data loss in less risk.

Answer (score 11):

You can not have an heterogeneous cluster with C* and Scylla nodes on the same cluster.

Create a separate scylla cluster, create the schema, change the app to do double writes (to both clusters) and then migrate the C* historical data to Scylla.

There are multiple ways to migrate the data. This should help: https://youtu.be/CDOesdWDT9Y No downtime, no problem there are options for that too.

Comment: This is the standard steps mentioned in migration docs but there are challenges in doing that. Basically when you have too many projects accessing and the database then its difficult to make dual writes on all projects, and if you have the higher nodes in Cassandra and would like to work on reduced nodes of Scylla, its difficult to shift old data.

Comment: That is understood, but migrations are disruptive and you might want to try and sustain a time window when only the essential clients are issuing writes (and set those to do double writes). When the migration is done, you can resume normal ops.

Comment: Frequently people will use a tool like Kafka to manage the multiplexing of writes. So you don't need to muck around with client code to deal with issues of consistency between the two databases. 
Agreed that it is less than ideal, but as dyasny said, any db migration is a  disruptive event. Luckily it is also rare. It should be much easier, though, than other migrations where you need to change your application's API and drivers to the DB.

Comment: @sachin Did you look into the scylla-migrator github? Also, the option Greg provided is a good one. It is only difficult to shift old data if you are using snapshots. But Spark, Kafka, and even sstableloader would work despite different topology.

Comment: @ScyllaGreg, Moreno Garcia Yes I looked around all the migrations documents and ways i can do but now i am looking for more reliable solution something like to get one single place where I can get all write update delete request of the Cassandra DB and triggered the same command on Scylla DB instead of enabling dual writes on all the application.

Comment: I think your description of a "more reliable solution" is not accurate. What you are looking for is a "more simple solution" that would require no migration and no downtime. 
You can wish for such a thing, but it is not supported. It is hard to imagine a scenario where any database could support such a wish.
If you are OK with a few minutes of maint. period, you can run Scylla on Cassandra-created SSTables. Which would mean no migration. But if you cannot sustain any downtime, your only choice is online migration, which will always require double-writes.

Answer (score 10):

While Scylla is compatible with Cassandra across several axes (SSTables, CQL/Drivers, etc.), Scylla did need to make some changes to the gossip protocol which make it impossible to join a Cassandra cluster. There is no known way to join Scylla to a Cassandra cluster.

Scylla has published several suggested techniques for migration.

Blog describing the techniques: https://www.scylladb.com/2019/04/02/spark-file-transfer-and-more-strategies-for-migrating-data-to-and-from-a-cassandra-or-scylla-cluster/

Webinar walking through the migration techniques [requires registration]: https://go.scylladb.com/wbn-spark-scylla-migration-strategies-registration.html

Documentation: https://docs.scylladb.com/operating-scylla/procedures/cassandra_to_scylla_migration_process/

Community Slack for Q&A: http://slack.scylladb.com